# What could I be doing wrong? TimeoutError when trying to scrape data from this specific site?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from "www . money . usnews .com" but I'm consistently getting this TimeoutError that says:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to
respond.
```

Here is my code: (I included a different website as a test case and it works. I am new to web scraping. What should I do?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


try:
    html = urlopen('https://money.usnews.com')
    # html = urlopen('http://www.timeanddate.com/weather/usa/los-angeles')
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e)
except URLError as e:
    print("No server")
except ValueError as e:
    print("NULL ")
else:
    print("b")
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
    print(bs.h1)
```